# Nongreedy regex with alternation and repetition

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the contents between `AB` and `BA` using extended regex, for instance using `awk`.

Consider the two example strings `AB12BABA` and `AB123BABA`, I tried the following regex

```
AB([^B]|([^B][^A]|B[^A]|[^B]A))*BA
```

But it matches the whole string (greedy) for both examples.

Can anyone explain how the regex engine works for this case, and how I should change my regex so that it would work.

Comment: adding question mark `*?` makes it lazy

Comment: @revo Not available in `awk` I think?

Comment: @BastiM No `*?` is not available, the tokens can only be used separately as `*` or `?`. The combination `*?` does not have any special interpreation in `awk` (like change meaning of `*` to become lazy)..

Comment: @HåkonHægland sorry, in this case i haven't said anything *vanishes*

Comment: @TimPietzcker I hoped to get an explanation of how the regex engine works, the example in this question just happend to be similar to the other question.. The other question was about finding the regex. This question is about how the regex engine works for alternation combined with repetition..

Comment: It looked very much like the old, non-working regex. Why aren't you using the regex from the other solution? Doesn't it do what you wanted? Which part of the explanation was unclear? I can try to explain it better.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, but I think I will study your solution more closely and come back to you later. I am also trying to understand how I can extend the solution to three characters like `ABC.*CBA`.. So I need to understand it more in depth..

Comment: An extension is going to be very difficult with a POSIX ERE engine, especially if the delimiters get longer. Why does it have to be awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BRE and ERE engines will match with the **Leftmost Longest Rule**, which is different from how Perl and other NFA-based regex engines matches the regex.

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/leftmost_longest_rule.html) from Boost library is more detailed in regards to the technical aspect, so I quote it here:

> ### The Leftmost Longest Rule
>
> Often there is more than one way of matching a regular expression at a particular location, for POSIX basic and extended regular expressions, the "best" match is determined as follows:
>
> 1. Find the leftmost match, if there is only one match possible at this location then return it.
> 2. Find the longest of the possible matches, along with any ties. If there is only one such possible match then return it.
> 3. If there are no marked sub-expressions, then all the remaining alternatives are indistinguishable; return the first of these found.
> 4. Find the match which has matched the first sub-expression in the leftmost position, along with any ties. If there is only on such match possible then return it.
> 5. Find the match which has the longest match for the first sub-expression, along with any ties. If there is only one such match then return it.
> 6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for each additional marked sub-expression.
> 7. If there is still more than one possible match remaining, then they are indistinguishable; return the first one found.

*Marked sub-expression* as mentioned in the text refers to `()` capturing groups. Note that they only does capturing and back-reference is not supported.

---

Therefore, in order to do a lazy matching, you need to construct a regular expression, such that it matches the repeated part, while **avoid** matching the tail part until the very end. Since ERE and BRE are equivalent to theoretical regular expression, as long as you can construct a DFA, there exists an equivalent regex that does the trick (just that constructing it is not trivial task in some cases).

For your requirement, this regex shall work:

```
AB([^B]|B+[^AB])*B*BA
```

The part `([^B]|B+[^AB])*B*` matches any string that does not contain the string "BA".

### Derivation

This is the DFA for matching **a string that does not contain the string "BA"**.

[image: DFA]

The notation here is not standard, so I will explain a bit:

- State q1/B means that the state is named q1 (just like how you name a variable), B is the current progress towards matching BA.
- `*` means any character in the alphabet. `[^B]` means any character in the alphabet except for B.

In the DFA, q0 and q1 are final states, q0 is the initial state. Note that q2 is a trap state, since it is a non-final state, and there is no transition out of this state.

Use the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120), or just use [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/) to derive the regular expression. (In JFLAP, you should use some character, such as `C` to represent `[^AB]`).

Since q2 is a trap state, we can exclude it from the formula:

```
R0 =  [^B]R0 + BR1 + λ
R1 = [^AB]R0 + BR1 + λ
```

Apply Arden's theorem to R1:

```
R1 = B*([^AB]R0 + λ)
```

Substitute R1 to R0:

```
R0 = [^B]R0 + BB*([^AB]R0 + λ) + λ
```

Distribute `BB*` over `([^AB]R0 + λ)`:

```
R0 = [^B]R0 + BB*[^AB]R0 + BB*λ + λ
```

Group together:

```
R0 = ([^B] + BB*[^AB])R0 + (BB* + λ)
```

Apply Arden's theorem to R0:

```
R0 = ([^B] + BB*[^AB])*(BB* + λ)
```

(`BB*` OR `λ` (empty string)) is equivalent to `B*`:

```
R0 = ([^B] + BB*[^AB])*B*
```

Let use rewrite it into `awk`'s syntax: `([^B]|B+[^AB])*B*`, which is what shown above.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for :) Can you explain step 4 in more detail? And how it relates to `([^AB]|B|[^B]A)*`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Since Tim Pietzcker's regex is incorrect, I am going to expand my answer and explain on how to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use look arounds and a non greedy quantifier:

```
(?<=AB).*?(?=BA)
```

If you want to match the delimiters too, simply:

```
AB.*?BA
```

Comment: This question is about ERE. There is no nongreedy quantifier available as far as I know..

Comment: @HåkonHægland oh. I can't test that - can you try and let me know?

Comment: Yes I checked the manual http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html. It is not available..

Comment: @HåkonHægland I couldn't find any reference to greedy/non greedy in that link. Are you sure? What does it say?